# Set ConnectionString at RunTime

Tags: c#, connection-string

I´m a beginner in C# programming.

I need to edit/set/change my connection string that I stored in my `app.config`, I'm using VS database wizard to create the queries.

If you could write the code it will be very nice :)

Comment: Which database are you using?, a little more context would be useful.

Comment: This may not be the most desirable depending on where the application is running from.  If the application is running in Windows 7 with the program files directory locked down - the user may not have permission to modify the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
using System.Configuration;

var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var connectionStrings = config.ConnectionStrings;
foreach (var connectionString in connectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
{
    // change connection details
}
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: I had to do something like this: foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connectionString in connectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
{
if (connectionString.Name == "myName")
    connectionString.ConnectionString = "myNewValue";
}