# How to get connection String from database and connect to it at runtime in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odbc

I am new in MVC i faced a problem that i have a dropdownlist on my form with branch Name and every branch have a separate Database and user login from central Database once user login and select any of branch i want to get connection String from Database and then connect to this connection String  at run time ..
Now i got the connection string from database table.i got connection string like this

```
name="ABCD" connectionString="Data Source=DELL27\SQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=TMLS;User ID=saver;Password=Abc123"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

The question is how to get connection to this Connection String? and get data from branch database

Comment: What DB are you using? What API are you using to manage the connexion to your DB? ODBC? OLE DB? Etc.

Comment: i am using ODBC

Comment: You will need to have a way to identify the needed DB from the user then you will have to pass the connection string in to a context class on creation of the class.

Comment: This is good but now i got a solution. put datasourse in database table in a column and use when needed in programming

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1:**
You could create an Entity Framework Entity Model for each of your databases using this [getting started guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). This will make accessing different databases really easy.

```
// Access Abcd
using (var db = new AbcdEntities())
{
    return db.Widgets.ToList();
}

// Access Efgh
using (var db = new EfghEntities())
{
    return db.Widgets.ToList();
}
```

**Option 2:** Alternatively, you could use a single connection string and update the connection string at run time ([see similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349734/set-connectionstring-at-runtime)). You could still use Entity Framework assuming your database schemas are all the same.

Comment: I put the datasourse that i want to use in a database table and use this when needed at run time . this work for me . thanks